# Flex-start and flex-end in one line

Tags: html, css, flexbox

How may I locate few elements in one line with `flex-start` property and few elements with `flex-end` in one line.

Comment: Use align-self for the specific elements and set flexend or start accordingly

Comment: @Geeky -- The user is asking how to position _elements in one line_, so using `align-self` won't work as it affect the cross axis.

Answer (score 37, accepted):

For the main axis, and with the default flex direction `row`, you should use the new *auto margins*, e.g. `margin-left: auto`.

***Edit:** And it appears that react now also support auto-margins: [github-link](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/350)*

```css
body > div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
}
div div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
}
div div:nth-child(3) {
  margin-left: auto;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

And like this for the cross axis, using the `align-*` properties, e.g. `align-self`.

```css
body > div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid red;
  align-items: flex-start;
  height: 100px;
}
div div {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightgray;
}
div div:nth-child(3),
div div:nth-child(4) {
  align-self: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
  <div>4</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. Using aling-self method it doesn't seem to work correctly. Is that ok?

Comment: @SergeyRyabov No, not as one expect, when using `row` direction.

Answer (score 16):

The easiest way to achieve this would be to use `justify-content: space-between;`:

```css
.parent {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
}

.parent > div {
    padding: 10px;
    background: grey;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
</div>
```

The first div will display as the flex-start and the second as a flex-end.

Answer (score 11):

Use a separator element to split:

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
.item {
    display: flex;
    flex-shrink: 0;
}
.divider {
    display: flex;
    flex: 1;
}

<div class=container>
    <div class=item>
        <div>Left One</div>
    </div>
    <div class=divider></div>
    <div class=item>
        <div>Right One</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Please avoid using `margin: auto` to flex boxes. This may not be supported by some native solutions such as `react native`.

Comment: Telling users to avoid the new and powerful _auto margins_ that came with flexbox is a bad suggestion. And since this is not a `react`-question, they are the perfect way to solve what is asked for. And FYI, react, better late than sorry, appears to have added it too now: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/350